# How to change a file generated by J2Objc

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, j2objc

Hello I have been trying for a while to changue the url from a file .m generated by the tool j2objc but xCode seems to not notice it, when I recompile the whole project it's still pointing to the url generated from the java file.

Could you help me to figure out how could i make this change, I have been looking for hours but i have couldn't.

Comment: Can you post the code you have that is relevant to your problem so we can see what you have done so far and any error messages you may be receiving as well?

Comment: I realized that it`s impossible to change the code of the source files of objetive-c. Because you can even delete the files and the project still  works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several intents  I find out that this is not possible, the reason is simple, when you compile the Java code with J2Objc the api generates .o files and .m & .h files just for reference, but the files that your iOS app is going to use are already compiled (*.o) so although you modify .m and .h will not take effect  because xCode is using the .o files generated by j2Objc.

So the solution is recompile again the changes with j2objc.